# Python - How to access elements in a list of lists to get empty values

Tags: python

I'm reading in a csv file and need to parse it. I want to have a validation check that makes sure no cell/value in the file has any empty values. My problem is that I don't know how to check each element in a list in a list of lists

In essence, I have a sample file with headers STATE, COST, and ID

```
VA,2000,1
CA,1
NY,3784,1
```

When parsing, I want a check that would throw an error on the second line since it's missing a value for the COST field.

Here is my code on how i'm approaching it:

```
with open('<hidden path url>', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    all_values = [line for line in csv_reader]
    headers = all_values[0]
    allocations = all_values[1:]

# Check for empty values
    if any(line == (None or '') for line in all_values):
        print("No column value can be empty")
    else:
        print("Success!")
```

This is the result of `print(all_values)`, aka the list of lists from which i'm trying to check each element for

```
[['state', 'cost', 'id'], ['VA', '2000' , '1'], ['CA', '', '1'], ['NY', '3784' , '1']]
```

Going through the check should print "No column values can be empty" since there is an empty value in the row ['CA'**, '',** '1']. I also don't want to define any extra function for the check.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An error in your code is that line == (None or '') is not valid to check whether its none or ''. It should instead be something like this:

```
if any(line == None or line == '' for line in all_values):
    print("No column value can be empty")
else:
    print("Success!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from syntax 
`line == (None or '')`
Try 
`line == None or line == ''`

Comment: Hi, no, the problem is that I can't access the elements in a list in a list of lists. line is just giving me each of the 4 lists separately as the elements, but I need it to check the actual elements inside of each of the 4 lists

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem! I created one big list that held all the elements in my list of lists and checked from there if any value was None or "".

```
    flat_1 = [x for l in allocations for x in l] #flatten/unpack list of lists

    if any(e == None or e == '' for e in flat_1):
        print("No column values can be empty")
    else:
        print("No empty values")
```